# Update jTextField in another swing gui class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

My problem is to update jTextField1 (update province) in class Province.java. 
The first GUI showing up is AddAddress which contains 4 fields ( jTextField ) to be filled in : province ( jTextField1), district(2), ward(3) . Each time double-click on jTextField1 or 2 or 3 or 4 a new JFrame appears showing province, district or ward list. After clicking, it returns back to the first GUI and the province/district/ward clicked is updated.

Comment: private void jList1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        JList theList = (JList) evt.getSource();
        if(evt.getClickCount() == 2){
            int index = theList.locationToIndex(evt.getPoint());
            Object object = theList.getModel().getElementAt(index);
          
        }
        this.setVisible(false);
        new AddAddress().setVisible(true);
    }

Comment: In class AddProvince . I use jpa to create class from the sql database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `JFrame` in situations like that. Actually using multiple frames in one application is a bad practice. Please read here: [The Use of Multiple JFrames: Good or Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-or-bad-practice).

I suggest you to use a `JDialog` to select province etc.

Here is a simple example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class JDialogDemo extends JFrame {

    public JDialogDemo() {

        final MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog(this);

        final JTextField provinceField = new JTextField(10);

        JButton button = new JButton("Show Dialog");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dialog.pack();
                dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(JDialogDemo.this);

                dialog.setVisible(true);

                provinceField.setText(dialog.getSelectedProvince());
            }
        });

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(provinceField);
        add(button);

        setSize(400, 400);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JDialogDemo();
    }
}

class MyDialog extends JDialog {

    private String selectedProvince;

    public MyDialog(Frame owner) {
        super(owner, true);

        setTitle("Provinces");

        final JList<String> list = new JList<String>(new String[]{"province1", "province2", "province3"});
        add(list);

        JButton okButton = new JButton("Ok");
        okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                selectedProvince = list.getSelectedValue();
                setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        add(okButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public String getSelectedProvince() {
        return selectedProvince;
    }

}
```

**Edit:**

Edit your `jTextField1MouseClicked` method

```
private void jTextField1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jTextField1MouseClicked
        // TODO add your handling code here:
      if(evt.getClickCount() == 2){
            AddProvince provinceDialog = new AddProvince();
            provinceDialog.setVisible(true);
            jTextField1.setText(provinceDialog.getSelectedProvince());
      }
}
```

Then make `AddProvince` extends from `JDialog`. And add a method which return the selected province.

Comment: Deadline is 2 days left. Can u show me how to do it :( ?

Comment: Check my example code.

Comment: It worked !! Thanks million times !!!

Comment: I'm a newbie to Java. Can u give me some material about creating Java apps ? I am new to this

Comment: I think the oracle tutorials are good resources for learn java with swing. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html

Comment: Also you can learn how to use swing components like `JDialog` in [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html)

Comment: https://github.com/hoangsonld95/MidTerm

Comment: It's my project. I got how to make jdialog but i'm still in trouble with my own problem. Some content  in gui is in vietnamese but if u look at the layout, u can understand .

Comment: Check my edit. You need to extend all of your frames from JDialog.